# partition without number in archlinux

Tags: archlinux

I was following this tutorial to install archlinux for the first time and I came across a problem.

http://www.linuxveda.com/2014/06/07/arch-linux-tutorial/3/

Typing in cgdisk /dev/sda showed I had 1 119.2 GiB of free space and it was a partition type of, "free space". However, creating a boot partition (or skipping it and going straight to the root directory in case of cfdisk for MBR), makes it so I have an extra 1007KiB sized partition that's a "free space" type partition. It's also at the top of the list and without a label...

Could anyone enlighten me as to what is going on here?

Comment: I would highly recommend installing using [Arch's official beginner's guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners'_guide). It lists common pitfalls as you go along, and allows you to read in as great of detail as you choose.

Answer (score 0):

It is the boot partition, which is [required](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=85728) in order to be able to boot off your hard drive.